# How to reduce size of zoom recorded powerpint presentation

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert a powerpoint presentation which is recorded from zoom to a smaller size.the feasibility is that since it was a powerpoint ppt,most frames are duplicate
Edit:This video contains popup of teachers video on top right corner and it is constantly changing.

Comment: Look on an answer for question: [Techniques for compressing a slideshow presentation video?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/18148)

Comment: If you're looking for a video editor to get rid of some sequences, product recommendations are off-subject here.

Comment: How was it recorded?

Comment: I recorded using zoom inbuilt recorder

Comment: @Lluser This video contains popup of teachers video on top right corner and it is constantly changing.